# Does auto_update_plugin Filter Work When Put In Theme's functions.php File

Tags: filters

I wanted to know if the (auto_update_plugin) and the (auto_update_theme) filters work when put in theme's functions.php file instead of config.php file in WordPress core.

Comment: which `config.php` is this? You shouldn't be modifying WP Core

Answer (score 1):

The filter works when placed in active theme's functions.php file. Just tested that, and the result was positive.

Answer (score 0):

In general they should. All of config load, plugins load, and theme load happens during load process and before `init` hook, which is considered a point after which load is done and functionality starts.

Unless you are dealing with early load-related events, typically plugin is perfectly appropriate place.

PS not sure what you mean by `config.php`, hooks don't even work as early as `wp-config.php` yet.